# Custom Listview with multiple lines per row

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

Basically, I need some rows to be 3 lines and others for the text to be centered on the middle line.  I already have the 3 lines working.  I just need to figure out how to check if the lines R.id.text2 and R.id.text3 are empty and set TAG_1 to be displayed on R.id.text2.  I'm posting what I think it relevent.  If more code is needed just let me know

```
ListAdapter simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, makeList,
        R.layout.custom_list_view,
        new String[] { TAG_1, TAG_2, TAG_3 }, new int[] { R.id.text1, R.id.text2, R.id.text3 });
  listView.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);
```

custom_list_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >


<TextView android:id="@+id/text1" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:textSize="19sp"/>
<TextView android:id="@+id/text2" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
<TextView android:id="@+id/text3" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SimpleAdapter` is pretty useless for displaying anything but the most basic list. You will have much more success extending your own adapter. Start with an [`ArrayAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html).

The basic concept is that you extend the adapter and implement its `getView()` function. In this you inflate (or reuse) a view for each row and populate it with your data.

There are many adapter tutorials on the internet, I found [this one](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-listview-with-adapter-example.html) with a quick search.

Understanding how to utilize adapters is a fundamental part of android development.